# Include a PHP filename after extracting the id from Database

Tags: php, include

So when I add a product, an id is assigned and a file is created with the product id, eg 1000.php. I don't know how to call it in the product.php file to be included:

I know what I did in the code pasted below is wrong but I don't know how to make it call the 1000.php file by extracting the id from sql first and then include it in the same file. Any advice?

```
<?php 
function between($start, $end, $string) {
    $string = ' ' . $string;
    $ini = strpos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0) return '';
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}
$pid = $_GET['id'];
$pid = trim($pid);
include('php/config.php');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE pid='".$pid."'";
    $result = $config->query($sql);
    $num_row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
       if($num_row == 1 ) {
         $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
         extract($row);
        $display = 1; } else { $display = 0; }
include('".$pid.".php');
```

Comment: Hi Mathew,

Please try `include $pid . '.php';`

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score -1):

If I'm understanding well what you are asking help for, before this line:
`include('".$pid.".php');`

you should create the file and write in it all the data you need in it; something like this could work:

```
<?php 
function between($start, $end, $string) {
    $string = ' ' . $string;
    $ini = strpos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0) return '';
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}
$pid = $_GET['id'];
$pid = trim($pid);
include('php/config.php');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE pid='".$pid."'";
    $result = $config->query($sql);
    $num_row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
       if($num_row == 1 ) {
         $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
         extract($row);
        $display = 1; } else { $display = 0; }
try {
 $handle = fopen($dir.$filename, 'x');//look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php on why to use 'x'
 fwrite($fp, $allTheDataYouWantToWrite);
 fclose($handle);
}catch(\Exception $e){
//do something if exception happens
}
```

After that you have the file created in that directory and its ready for using it
Take in account that `include` is used to read php code and maybe is not that what you want...

Comment: Actually the file already exists. Once I add the product it will also generate the file with the same id. Afterwards if I access /product/id (product.php being the file which includes the code above) , I want it to read the file generated (id.php).

Comment: @Mathew as i told you in my answer, include is used to let php parser know that you are including php code for use in you current file and that included file should start with <?php

Comment: @Mathew as i told you in my answer, include is used to let php parser know that you are including php code for use in you current file. If the 'someId.php' file has something else rather than php code, you need to read the content of the file using some function like `file_get_contents($fileName)` into a variable, then parse it and use it.

Comment: @Mathew by the way, could you please upvote my answer...some one here downvoted me ... :)